# Is it possible to have multi-column layout for a smart capture form built using the new Content Builder in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, smart-capture

I am using the new Content Builder and all my smart capture fields are currently coming in a single column one after the other. Is there a way to place them side by side or i.e. have a 3 column layout ?

I know this can be done in the Classic editor but it does not expose the HTML and that is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately not without going into the HTML. To avoid having to go in the CSS, you should be able to set it up using CSS selectors in the page's STYLE tag. Problem is it might be hard to get the desired results when accounting for all the possibilities.

Comment: Yeah I tried going into the HTML, forcing it to be 2 column form layout all in the same 'Form field' so as to be mobile responsive where it will be 2 column on desktop and 1 column on mobile. However this will mess up the submit functionality.